# ggmap geocode function returns same lat and lon coords many different addresses - batch geocode

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I'm using the geocode function in ggmap on tens of thousands of addresses and getting a problem where the google API returns the same lat and lon coords for all my addresses which are very different (different cities and different zip codes).

I'm basically using this bit of code as an example: 
http://www.storybench.org/geocode-csv-addresses-r/

Here is my code.  A sample output of what I'm getting is in the link at the bottom of the code.  Thanks in advance and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
origAddress <- read.csv("C:/Projects/address_list2014.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#combine street, city and state into one column separated by a comma
origAddress$addresses <- paste(origAddress$street, ",", origAddress$city, ",", origAddress$state)

geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress))
{
  # Print("Working...")
  result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", api = "google", 
                    key = "My_google_api_key")
  origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I can't reproduce your problem.  Are you sure the code pasted above is exactly the same as the code you are running, maybe you have a 1 instead of an i.  Maybe you are having a time out issue and the variable is not being refreshed on each loop.  Try adding a `print(result)` to the loop to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this a bit more I finally found the issue.  Some of these addresses had a symbol: "#" used for the unit or apartment number and the # was causing some type of issue with the code.  Once I removed all # signs the code ran clean.